# At what value of $x$ does this function attain a local maximum?

Tags: calculus

Consider the function $f(x)=\int_x^{2x}\frac{\sin t}{t}dt$, At what value of $x$ on the interval $(0,\frac{3\pi}{2})$ does this function attain a local maximum?

Using the fundamental theorem of calculus, we have $f'(x)=\frac{\sin 2x}{x}-\frac{\sin x}{x}=0$, and from this we get that $\sin x(2\cos x-1)=0$, and so $x=\pi$ or $x=\pi/3$.

How do we know from here which value for $x$ is correct? Do we need to substitute both values into the expression for $f$ and integrate?

Comment: $f(\pi)$ is negative while $f(\pi/3)$ is positive, so guess what the $\text{argmax}$ is.

Answer (score 0):

You should compute the second derivative.

If $f''(x)>0$ then the choice of $x$ provides a minimum.

If $f''(x)<0$ then the choice of $x$ provides a maximum.

This is known, by some, as the second derivative test.